# getSymbol() in java.util.Currency returns different values depending on API level

Tags: java, android, currency

The following code is being used to format a number in the proper currency:

```
public static String getFormattedCurrency(String currencyCode, String currencyName, Number value) {

    //....

    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());                                           
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);                                                   
    format.setCurrency(currency);                                                                             
    if (format instanceof DecimalFormat) {                                                                    
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(CURRENCY_MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS);                                        
    }                                                                                                         
    Log.d("Currency", "Symbol: " + currency.getSymbol() + ", Currency: " + currency + ", Locale: " + local);          
    return format.format(value);
}
```

The value of `currencyCode` is `THB`, the Thai baht. On Lollipop, `currency.getSymbol()` returns `฿`, the sign for the Thai baht. However, on Oreo, the same method returns `THB`.

Why are different values being returned between these two API levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37068142), it would appear to be [a Unicode decision](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/7618).